# Python requests throwing SSLEOFError

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests, tls1.2

I am trying to connect a Python Requests POC to [this tool](https://github.com/commoncriteria/tls-cc-tools/). I am specifically looking at the test cases for FIA-X509 Ext 1.1. However, the Python POC is throwing the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hussain/Desktop/pythonVenv/python36Venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 601, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/home/hussain/Desktop/pythonVenv/python36Venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 346, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/home/hussain/Desktop/pythonVenv/python36Venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 850, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/home/hussain/Desktop/pythonVenv/python36Venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 326, in connect
    ssl_context=context)
  File "/home/hussain/Desktop/pythonVenv/python36Venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 329, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 407, in wrap_socket
    _context=self, _session=session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 814, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 1068, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 689, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLEOFError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:777)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hussain/Desktop/pythonVenv/python36Venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 440, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/home/hussain/Desktop/pythonVenv/python36Venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 639, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/home/hussain/Desktop/pythonVenv/python36Venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 388, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='10.0.0.221', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:777)'),))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "req.py", line 91, in <module>
    r = session.request('GET', 'https://10.0.0.221', verify=True)
  File "/home/hussain/Desktop/pythonVenv/python36Venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 508, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/hussain/Desktop/pythonVenv/python36Venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 618, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/hussain/Desktop/pythonVenv/python36Venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 506, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='10.0.0.221', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:777)'),))
```

This is the POC code that i am using to connect to it:

> ```
> import ssl
> import requests
>
> from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
> from requests.packages.urllib3.poolmanager import PoolManager
> from requests.packages.urllib3.util import ssl_
>
> CIPHERS = (
>     'RSA+AES'
> )
>
> class TlsAdapter(HTTPAdapter):
>     def __init__(self, ssl_options=0, **kwargs):
>         self.ssl_options = ssl_options
>         super(TlsAdapter, self).__init__(**kwargs)
>
>     def init_poolmanager(self, *pool_args, **pool_kwargs):
>         ctx = ssl_.create_urllib3_context(ciphers=CIPHERS, cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED, options=self.ssl_options)
>
>         self.poolmanager = PoolManager(*pool_args,
>                                        ssl_context=ctx,
>                                        **pool_kwargs)
>
> session = requests.session()
>
> adapter = TlsAdapter(ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1 | ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_1)
> session.mount("https://", adapter)
> r = session.request('GET', 'https://10.0.0.221', verify=True)
> print(r)
> ```

Can anyone please help me in figuring out what i am missing here and how can this be resolved? I tried looking up the problem on the requests github issue page as well as on stackoverflow but none of them seemed to work for me.

Thanks!